# Checking if a cell in one column is in a row beneath the last entry of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am finding explaining this quite difficult, so please ask me to attempt to better my explanation if it is not clear enough.

I have a column, say column A, which is continuously growing, but some cells in column A are empty.  I am trying to write a formula such that for a blank element in Column A, look ahead to the end of the column. If any of the elements in Column A are non-empty, then the element in Column B in the same row as the blank element will say `FALSE`. For every non-empty element in Column A, the Column B entry of that row should say `TRUE`. Here is an example in one particular state of time:

`Column A   Column B
    1    |    TRUE
    2    |    TRUE
    3    |    TRUE
         |   FALSE
    5    |    TRUE
    6    |    TRUE
    7    |    TRUE
         |   FALSE
    9    |    TRUE
    10   |    TRUE
    A    |    TRUE
    B    |    TRUE
         |   FALSE
         |   FALSE
    E    |    TRUE`

All further elements in Column A are blank, and as such, all further elements in Column B are blank. [Here is another example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqpk7.jpg)

Comment: My bad, I just manually wrote TRUE or FALSE for that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula would be:

```
=IF(MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)>=ROW(),IF(A1<>"","To Be","Not to be"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly for my example, thank you. Now how would I edit this to evaluate a formula or not rather than printing TRUE or FALSE? For example, how could I print YES instead if TRUE, and leave blank if FALSE?

Comment: That is not what was asked. @KOB

Comment: The description of my problem states that I only want the output of a formula in column B to be printed if it is not passed the last row of column A. In hindsight, my example was a poor choice using TRUE and FALSE, I should have asked to print "YES" or "NO" instead.

Comment: @KOB see edit, please next time elaborate what it is you are doing with the formula.  I assume you will be putting another formula in the True space.  It you had stated that I would have provided that, as it was I provided the shorted formula to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Excellent, thank you - and sorry for the miscommunication.